How to use FontAwesome Icons in Froala 4.3 in a Vue 2 Project?
Anybody knows how to use FontAwesome Icons in Froala 4.3 in a Vue 2 Project (I can't use Vue 3 for this Project)?
I added FontAwesome like it is documented and already working in other projects inside the main.js:
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'
import { faBold } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

library.add(faBold)

Vue.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon)

I added Froala inside the main.js like this:
import VueFroala from 'vue-froala-wysiwyg'

require('froala-editor/js/froala_editor.pkgd.min.js')
require('froala-editor/css/froala_editor.pkgd.min.css')
require('froala-editor/css/froala_style.min.css')

Vue.use(VueFroala)

I also added a custom icon template for using <font-awesome-icon> instead of <i> like this inside a compontent:
<script>
import FroalaEditor from 'froala-editor'
FroalaEditor.DefineIconTemplate('font_awesome_legacy', '<font-awesome-icon icon="fa-solid fa-[NAME]" aria-hidden="true"></font-awesome-icon>')
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      model: '',
      config: {
        iconsTemplate: 'font_awesome_legacy',
        placeholderText: 'Add your content here ...',
        charCounterCount: false,
        toolbarBottom: true,
      },
    }
  },
}
</script>

But the froala doesn't render and icon:

Even though the HTML for rendeing FontAwesome Icons is correct.
What am I missing here?
Thanks in advance!
